# How to check if a visitor is using the latest version of his/her browser?

Tags: version, browser-detection

Is there a simple and automatic way of checking if a visitor to my website (written in asp.net) is using the latest version of his browser? This would allow me to display a message to inform them that they're running an old version and that they might want to upgrade.

My website is tested on most broswers but I don't test old versions (such as Internet Explorer 6 etc). When one of my visitors is using such an old version, basically, I would like to **encourage** (not force) them to upgrade.

Of course I could do this myself by getting the version of the browser and look it up in my database but I don't want to have to maintain a 'browser version' database myself.
Any ideas?

Comment: What plattform is your website built on (ASP.NET, PHP,...)?

Comment: [Detect version of browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser)

Answer (score -2):

Speaking as a user of websites, if I come across a site that advised me to upgrade my browser then that would be an immediate black mark against that site.

I might not be able to upgrade (if I'm accessing from a corporate network for example); I might have a specific reason for using a particular version (if I'm a web developer wanting to ensure compatibility with my user community for example).

So personally, I would say that a blanket disclaimer that you don't test this site on earlier versions would be the way to go. That's quite apart from the technical challenge of what you want to do.

---

**Edit:** as Yeti points out, however valid my concerns, I don't answer the question directly. This is done in [Pace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/720837/83109), and the w3schools resource he points to gives you what you need to do this on the client side.

Comment: This totally depends on the situation!
Please, first give an answer, and then think about warning the user about how to use the answer. Without the answer the OP cannot do anything!! It's so frustrating to see answers like: "Why would you do that?"

Comment: It's an answer from a long time ago. Looking back on it, yes, I agree with you. Just given Pace a +1 for pointing to that particular resource which is one way to do it. I certainly think my warning should stand, but have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @DavidM You should know better than to rely on links like that. The reason why link only answers are discouraged is because they break–like that one did.