# how can I redirect users depending on their browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I have a site that is not compatible with older versions of internet explorer. Rather than ruin the experience for non-IE users, I would like to redirect IE users to another, compatible version of the same site when they enter my url. is this possible?

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first! Searching `how can I redirect users depending on their browser?` seems to produce very useful results; if necessary, add the technology as a keyword, say "javascript" or "html".  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't use those words when I googled and thus I couldn't find anything useful. I don't start questions without doing a bit of research before hand, and I'm sorry for the dis-convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser) :

> ```
> navigator.sayswho= (function(){
>     var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
>     var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
>     if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
>     M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
>     return M;
> ```
>
> })(); navigator.sayswho[0] is the (string) version

All you have to do is :

```
var browser = navigator.sayswho[0];
if(browser == "MSIE") {
    document.location.href = "you.new.url.html";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [IE's conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do this for older version of IE. For instance:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/your/other/page" />
<![endif]-->
```

They're no longer supported in IE10, but then, you probably don't need to do the redirection with IE10, either.

Answer (score 1):

There is a comment function to do that.

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
  Redirect your page here.
<![endif]-->
```

And for the redirecion itself, you can use javascript, or meta header :

With JavaScript:

```
<script>window.location = "http://www.my-new-page.com/"</script>
```

With the meta

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.my-new-page.com/">
```