# Zend Framework 2 redirect if old browser how?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, zend-framework2

I need to redirect in a page (not supported) users that use Ie 8 or older version
how can i do? a helper?
second question if i give user chance to procede anyway i have to store this preference in sessions?

thanks 
Stefano

Comment: Can you tell us what your research on the first question showed and what is your second question? It is not very clear

Comment: It is better to do the browser check in the browser if possible. Depending on your use case, you may be able to do this in JavaScript instead. Something to consider at least.

Comment: I would go for a conditional comment and simply put up an alert box on top of the screen, asking the user to proceed to another version of the website. Don't do such things with scripts, users generally don't like automatism they don't ask for ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution

**onBootstrap** seems to be correct but without possibility of chance to proceed.
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.get-browser.php

Other solution
**check with javascript** [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser)
is the better solution and store it in cookies

Comment: i know these functions but i want to now the best way to do it in zend framework 2

Comment: finally i create a class that detects user browser and then i put an event in the module file using sessions