# How to prompt user again for awareness setting after a user has said no?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, location, location-aware

I have a situation where most of an application's functionality is based on location awareness.  When a user says no to location awareness, they often desire to change this to allow it after they come to this realization.

Is JavaScript or other such trigger to allow a user to change this preference once it has been set vs allowing the timeout to expire or to go through the browser settings to change it?  My goal is to add a button that will allow the user to simply click it to get the browser to prompt them again for the authorization.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is asking user if he allow it and showing how it will be used and what are the benefits before browser will.

Comment: This is already done; but there must be a trigger to clear the current browser setting and then allow the user to make their selection again.  I'm not readily finding this aspect of it.

Comment: @ylluminate I'm pretty sure that there is no other way. It will be against user first policy. I saw this solution many times: When browser asks for permission you can show image of a browser window with this pop-up and explain what user should choose. But probably you can bypass it by using subdomains.

Comment: Hmm, that is unfortunate because the way I want to present this is very non-intrusive and would allow a user to easily make the choice again.  Further, can you point me to an example of a very well done example that you've seen along the lines of what you suggest?

Comment: @ylluminate If you could do this then some malicious developers will spam user with this request until he accept it. Example of the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343804/assisting-users-in-spotting-the-html5-geolocation-prompt But probably red color is a bit alarming :) Adobe also had interesting way for the Flash Player download page. They detect browser and show, in the middle of the screen, exact image of the pop-up(that is shown) with the right option selected so it won't be confusing.