# Font looks really worse in Firefox: why and how I can write a hack for Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

Here is an example:

First - how it looks in Chrome, second -in Firefox (hardly readable).

CSS:

```
 font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
```

Can you please provide an example, how I can make this element's font bold only if browser is Firefox?

[image]

Comment: Because Firefox sucks at font rendering. And a bunch of other stuff. More accurately, IE and Chrome use advanced font rendering techniques to make text a lot easier to read - this is mostly tied in with the operating system. Firefox rolls their own font renderer, which does not.

Comment: See [this Coding Horror article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/font-rendering-respecting-the-pixel-grid.html) for a little more info.

Comment: @Kolink, that really sucks. And what should i do?

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing you can do. Firefox has been bumming me out since Version 4 with how much it's been sucking >_>

Comment: This probably isn't affecting your font rendering at all, but font names with spaces in them should be quoted. --Personally, I think fonts look better in Firefox than in Chrome. Fonts in Chrome aren't aliased as crisply.

Comment: There's nothing you *can* do about it.  Firefox users are likely used to their browser rendering fonts poorly.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: "Because Firefox sucks at font rendering. And a bunch of other stuff. More accurately, IE and Chrome use advanced font rendering techniques"* What??? On my machine Chrome fonts are A LOT worse than Firefox's, which are pretty much perfect. Chrome 35, Firefox 29.01 (both current versions), system is Windows 7. I have found lots of similar user experiences while searching Google to find a solution for my ugly Chrome fonts. [Just one example.](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7084374)

Answer (score 0):

When I test 13px Arial, it looks slighty lighter in Chrome than in Firefox, rather than the other way around as in your case. Stay tuned to variation across browser versions, platforms, and settings, as regards to font rendering.

Usual [browser detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser/5918791) techniques could be used in JavaScript to check whether the browser claims to be Firefox and modify CSS code accordingly. But this would be a shot in the dark, partly due to the variation mentioned, partly because there is really nothing you can do to fix the assumed problem. Bolding tends to change the overall appearance of text, not just slighly thicken strokes, and bolding often *reduces* readability.

Ways to avoid creating problems like this: Do not set font size to something as small as 13px. Especially for small font sizes, use black (or something very dark) on white (or other very luminous) background, instead of the opposite, and in particular avoid making the color contrast too small.

Answer (score 0):

it seems firefox can only take 2 background url in css... if it has a 3rd the font makes that blurry/pixelated effect. NEVER THE LESS.... i found that its true on a windows XP. the same firefox on a windows 8 works fine. (I was surprised) i might think it has something to do with the "use hardware if available" option in forefox.

Try removing a background "image" or "color" from one of the table's CSS.... if its solved then... firefox sucks.