# For the same browser getting different version info with different URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

Hi  I have a requirement to detect the browser version via JavaScript. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser) i am able to get what i expected. However, the version that returned is different when i access the page via localhost and via hostname.

Create a simple HTML page (BrowserVersion.html) with below source.

```
<html>
<script>

var BrowserDetect = {
    init: function () {
    this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
    this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
    || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
    || "an unknown version";
    this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";
    },
    searchString: function (data) {
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var dataString = data[i].string;
    var dataProp = data[i].prop;
    this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
    if (dataString) {
    if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
    return data[i].identity;
    }
    else if (dataProp)
    return data[i].identity;
    }
    },
    searchVersion: function (dataString) {
    var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
    if (index == -1) return;
    return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index+this.versionSearchString.length+1));
    },
    dataBrowser: [
    {
    string: navigator.userAgent,
    subString: "Chrome",
    identity: "Chrome"
    },
    { string: navigator.userAgent,
    subString: "OmniWeb",
    versionSearch: "OmniWeb/",
    identity: "OmniWeb"
    },
    {
    string: navigator.vendor,
    subString: "Apple",
    identity: "Safari",
    versionSearch: "Version"
    },
    {
    prop: window.opera,
    identity: "Opera"
    },
    {
    string: navigator.vendor,
    subString: "iCab",
    identity: "iCab"
    },
    {
    string: navigator.vendor,
    subString: "KDE",
    identity: "Konqueror"
    },
    {
    string: navigator.userAgent,
    subString: "Firefox",
    identity: "Firefox"
    },
    {
    string: navigator.vendor,
    subString: "Camino",
    identity: "Camino"
    },
    { // for newer Netscapes (6+)
    string: navigator.userAgent,
    subString: "Netscape",
    identity: "Netscape"
    },
    {
    string: navigator.userAgent,
    subString: "MSIE",
    identity: "Explorer",
    versionSearch: "MSIE"
    },
    {
    string: navigator.userAgent,
    subString: "Gecko",
    identity: "Mozilla",
    versionSearch: "rv"
    },
    { // for older Netscapes (4-)
    string: navigator.userAgent,
    subString: "Mozilla",
    identity: "Netscape",
    versionSearch: "Mozilla"
    }
    ],
    dataOS : [
    {
    string: navigator.platform,
    subString: "Win",
    identity: "Windows"
    },
    {
    string: navigator.platform,
    subString: "Mac",
    identity: "Mac"
    },
    {
    string: navigator.userAgent,
    subString: "iPhone",
    identity: "iPhone/iPod"
    },
    {
    string: navigator.platform,
    subString: "Linux",
    identity: "Linux"
    }
    ]
    };
    BrowserDetect.init();
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    navigator.sayswho= (function(){
  var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
  var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
  if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
  M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
  return M;
 })();
 alert(navigator.sayswho);
 </script>

<html>
```

Now when I access above page with below URL I am getting the value as, MSIE,8.0

```
http://localhost:8080/docs/BrowserVersion.html,
```

But when I access the same page with below URL I am getting the value as MSIE,7.0.

```
http://mylocalhost:8080/docs/BrowserVersion.html
```

Why the browser version is changing between two version of URLs.

Note: My host file has below entries

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   mylocalhost
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to disable IE's compatibility view for local domains.

Go to IE's compatibility view setting and uncheck the second option "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View".

---

The *VERY* basics of DOM object detection for browsers/browser versions...

```
var z = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

if (z.style.MozBinding!=undefined)
{
 browser='Firefox';
}
else if (window.opera)
{
//Opera up to 12.5
}
else if (z.style.scrollbar3dLightColor!=undefined)
{
 browser='msie';
}
else if (z.style.khtmlMarginBottomCollapse!=undefined && z.style.WebkitBorderRadius==undefined) {browser='Safari'; browser_version='2.0';}
else if (z.style.WebkitBorderRadius!=undefined || z.style.khtmlMarginBottomCollapse!=undefined)
{
 if (z.style.item=='function item() { [native code] }')
 {
  browser='Chrome';
 }
 else
 {
  browser='Safari';
 }
}
else if (z.style.KhtmlBorderRadius!=undefined) {browser='Konqueror';
```

Comment: ...and keep in mind that User-Agent string detection is evil and the code above will fail in IE11, whose `User-Agent` header does not contain `MSIE`.

Comment: @EricLaw Very true! Updated my answer to include basic DOM based browser detection.