# browser detection for safari 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, user-agent

How can I detect if a browser is safari 7 and further versions using user agent ?

The method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser/5916928) returns Safari 537.71 for a safari 7 browser. Is this safe to use for safari 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body>
<div id="example"></div>

<script>
console.log(navigator);
txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Language: " + navigator.language + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Online: " + navigator.onLine + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent language: " + navigator.systemLanguage + "</p>";

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;

</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

I think this will solve your problem

Comment: It didn't solve it but it helped. I found the solution by browsing the navigator in the console.

Comment: if you can please tick the ans if it helped you or an upvote ;)