# Browser Name Detection

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write JS script to detect browser Name and version at the moment my script detects the browser name i.e; Firefox, Safari, IE, Chrome. The code to find the Name of the Browser works fine but some parts of it I found Online and I would like if some one could explain one part of the JS code that i don't really understand and cant find an answer on Google.

OK the below example is used to detect Chrome, IE Browser:

```
var chrome = navigator.userAgent;
        if ((chrome.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1){    
            document.write("Chrome Dude ");
        }

    var ie = navigator.userAgent;
    if((ie.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1){
        document.write("IE Dude ");
    }
```

The part of this code that I dont understand is in within the if statement and exacly `!=-1`

Also having detected the Browser what how can I detect its Version...?

Answer (score 0):

It checking to find the string "Chrome" inside the navigator.uerAgent string. And if it returns -1 it means it is not found; Therefore is it is not equal to -1 then the string is found and indexOf returns the index (place) where the string "Chrome" is found.

Comment: OK but in this case it can also be !=0 because 0 is false/Null there fore the string "Chrome is not found"

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Read the manual of indexOf. If the string is not found, it returns -1. It does not return null or 0 id the string is not found. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this code for understanding purposes it's ok, but if you want to do browser detection to use some features don't to that, use feature detection instead (http://modernizr.com/).

Your che code check the requested substring in `navigator.userAgent` using `indexOf`:

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element
>   can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present

if not present the method returns -1, you are checking if the string is found so if the result `!=-1` (read is not -1).

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

To get the browser version check this QA: [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser)

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer. This example will `alert()` you the browser name, but the tweaked version below that will `document.write()` the browser name and version, followed by "Dude".

For documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator

## Normal

````
var sBrowser, sUsrAg = navigator.userAgent;

// The order matters here, and this may report false positives for unlisted browsers.

if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Mozilla Firefox";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("SamsungBrowser") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Samsung Internet";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SAMSUNG SM-G955F Build/PPR1.180610.011) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/9.4 Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Mobile Safari/537.36
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Opera") > -1 || sUsrAg.indexOf("OPR") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Opera";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 OPR/57.0.3098.106"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Trident") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Zoom 3.6.0; wbx 1.0.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Microsoft Edge (Legacy)";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Edg") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Microsoft Edge (Chromium)";
  // Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.64
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Chrome") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Google Chrome or Chromium";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/66.0.3359.181 Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Apple Safari";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1 980x1306"
} else {
  sBrowser = "unknown";
}

alert("You are using: " + sBrowser);```
````

## Tweaked

````
var sBrowser, sUsrAg = navigator.userAgent;

// The order matters here, and this may report false positives for unlisted browsers.

if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Mozilla Firefox";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("SamsungBrowser") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Samsung Internet";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SAMSUNG SM-G955F Build/PPR1.180610.011) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/9.4 Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Mobile Safari/537.36
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Opera") > -1 || sUsrAg.indexOf("OPR") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Opera";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 OPR/57.0.3098.106"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Trident") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Zoom 3.6.0; wbx 1.0.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Microsoft Edge (Legacy)";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Edg") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Microsoft Edge (Chromium)";
  // Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.64
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Chrome") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Google Chrome or Chromium";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/66.0.3359.181 Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Apple Safari";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1 980x1306"
} else {
  sBrowser = "unknown";
}

document.write(sBrowser + " " + navigator.appVersion + " Dude");```
````

### Live Result

```js
var sBrowser, sUsrAg = navigator.userAgent;

// The order matters here, and this may report false positives for unlisted browsers.

if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Mozilla Firefox";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("SamsungBrowser") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Samsung Internet";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SAMSUNG SM-G955F Build/PPR1.180610.011) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/9.4 Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Mobile Safari/537.36
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Opera") > -1 || sUsrAg.indexOf("OPR") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Opera";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 OPR/57.0.3098.106"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Trident") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Zoom 3.6.0; wbx 1.0.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Microsoft Edge (Legacy)";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Edg") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Microsoft Edge (Chromium)";
  // Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.64
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Chrome") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Google Chrome or Chromium";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/66.0.3359.181 Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {
  sBrowser = "Apple Safari";
  // "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1 980x1306"
} else {
  sBrowser = "unknown";
}
var browserdude = sBrowser + " " + navigator.appVersion + " Dude";
document.getElementById("_stackusertest").innerText = browserdude;
```

```html
<div id="_stackusertest"></div>
```

This tweaked version will also work for more browsers than just IE and Chrome.

**EDIT**

This is reason it must be != -1

The .indexOf(); function returns the position it is in the text.
0 is the first character in the text. -1, however, does not make any sense to the browser.
So lets say navigator.userAgent returns:

Mozilla/5.0 ([some os]) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36

and we are looking at:

navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1

If this returns true, this means Chrome is not located at the character at -1, since that doesn't make sense, technically asking if navigator.userAgent contains "Chrome", Which, in this case, is true.