# Getting browser version in javascript

Tags: browser, version

When I try to get browser version with window.navigator.userAgent it displays Mozilla on Internet Explorer too. I tried navigator.appCodeName before, but it was the same problem.
What could be the reason ? 
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you detect the version of a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 10 and above versions behave differently from IE 9 and below. When using javascript you need to handle those scenarios differently. Following code worked for me :)

```
    //MSStream object supported only for IE 10 and 11 (hope this will work for above IE 11 too .. )
    var isIE10or11 = window.MSStream;

    //FormData object allow you to send form data as key and value pairs with ajax requests. Supported in modern browsers.
    var isFormDataSupported = (window.FormData !== undefined);

    if(isIE10or11 && isFormDataSupported){
       alert('IE 10 or 11');
    }
    else if(!isIE10or11  && isFormDataSupported){
       alert('HTML 5 browser Excluding IE');
    }
    else{
       //Neither supports MSStream nor FormData object
       alert('IE Version 9 or below');
    }
```