# Make the background go blank and redirect for IE 8 and earlier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

In the website, the support in IE is from version 9 onwards. So when I open it behaves properly (as i have IE 8), showing an alert. Picture included

[image]

However I don't want the background image to be loaded (which is getting loaded in my case).
Only a blank screen displaying the alert info. How to achieve that?

This is the script I have used

```
 if(browsername=="Internet Explorer")
  {
    if(browserver<9.0)
    {
        alert("Your browser version is "+bowser.version+" and the minimum required version for this website is 9.0.So please use IE 9+.");
        window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
        //alert(bowser.name+","+bowser.version);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Need more code to tell.

Comment: what else do I need to add

Comment: If you don't want the background image to be loaded, then you will have to add the background in with JS instead of with CSS. If you do not care about it being loaded or not and just want to change it to white, then do `$("body").css("background", "#fff");`

Comment: I tried with the second one dint worked any help on the first idea

Comment: you need to create a custom popup or you can use jqueryui. wiht javascript alert this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

suppose your background is body background then put:

```
$("body").css("background","");
```

before the alert() code.

Comment: u mean something like this

$("body").css("background","");


  alert("Your browser version is "+bowser.version+" and the minimum required version for this website is 9.0.So please use IE 9+.");

Comment: The image would still be loaded by the browser.

Comment: @ Derek true 
Image is still getting loaded

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most optimal/appropriate way to handle the case.
But in my case I just used the

```
$('#divid').hide();
```

before the alert statement

Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've think you must do lazy loading of your background image.

1. Check the browser, to check you must use this [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser)
2. If browser is higher or equal than IE9 use code:

   `<body data-lazy-image="path-to-image"></body>`

   `var lazy = $("body").attr("data-lazy-image");`
   `$("body").css("backgroundImage",lazy);`

something like this.