# how to block html content if browser is IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Suppose the following very simple HTML code:

```
<div> Hi!</div>
```

I want to make this div not to show (to disable it, to block it) in case the browser is IE8. How may I do this?
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser/16938481#16938481

Comment: The answer to this is all over the net buddy

Comment: google IE stylesheet  First

Comment: If it's a bigger html fragment you should consider not sending it in the first place by doing a server side detection of IE8 ... or pass a client side detection to the server with which to decide whether to send selectable content to different browsers ... and this solution gives you a way to deal with newer version of IE as they don't support conditional statements

Comment: May I ask why you want to do like this? .. there might be other ways to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional statements for this, in your case something like this..

```
<![if !(IE 8)]>
<div> Hi!</div>
<![endif]>
```

that should do it.

Comment: How this code may work since it is understood as comment? I 've written it, however "Hi!" never appears whatever browser I use. What am I saying wrong?

Comment: should work in any browser that's not ie 8... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX

Comment: Please have a look at www.elgrecoweb.gr. I 've added           <!--[if !(IE 8)]>
      <p> Hi!</p>
   <![endif]-->                                                   Why it does not work? It is supposed to be placed next to the circle on the top left...

Answer (score 1):

Use the below Code

```
 <!--[if IE 8 ]>    
   <div> Hi! </div> 
 <![endif]-->
```

Comment: I think you want to place a `!` in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

First google answer:
[IE only stylesheet](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 1):

Try conditional statements for IE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx

Using pure HTML

```
<!--[if !IE8]-->
<div>Hi!</div>
<!--[endif]-->
```

If you want to hide it using css then you can create IE specific css

```
<div class="hideIE"> Hi!</div>
 <!--[if IE 8]>
    <style>
      .hideIE
      {
       display:none;
      }
    </style>
 <![endif]-->
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ankur1990/38jxv/

Comment: How this code may work since it is understood as comment? I 've written it, however "Hi!" never appears whatever browser I use. What am I saying wrong?

Comment: <!-- --> these are considered to be comments in html but IE has the extra property of understanding them as downlevel-hidden conditional comment if condition we have written is correct. checkout the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Found a way to do this using pure HTML and CSS also.Check it out

Comment: Please have a look at www.elgrecoweb.gr. I 've added           <!--[if !(IE 8)]>
      <p> Hi!</p>
   <![endif]-->                                                   Why it does not work? It is supposed to be placed next to the circle on the top left...

Comment: Have you tried this code: <!--[if !IE8]-->
<div>Hi!</div>
<!--[endif]-->

Comment: Ok. Then CSS is the solution according to me. Follow the second part (making display:none only for IE). that will work for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Hide div using style

```
<!--[if IE 8]>    
    <style>
        div { display:none;} 
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

OR, If you want to check for < IE 8

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <style>
        div { display:none;} 
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML 5 boiler plate:

```
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
```

then you can use:

```
if( $("html").hasClass("ie8") ) { 
    $('div.ie8').hide();
};
```

to hide any div with class `ie8` if current browser is `IE8`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <style type="text/css">
          .yourdiv {display:none;}
        </style>
<![endif]-->
```