# fix a javascript page that uses getyear()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, deprecated

I have a problem with a web page using the function getyear().
The page is part of our parent company's website, but I don't have control over it.
It is trying to validate an input date by comparing the four-digit year 2014 to checkdate.getyear() which returns 114. Obviously this will never succeed.

The answer I get from the parent company is 'Use IE Version 9 or less'. And under those situations, getyear() returns 2014.

Is there a way to get this javascript to work WITHOUT actually rolling back the browser to IE9? A way to run IE in 'ie9' mode? A way to inject code into the page?

I have very very little javascript knowledge so I'm looking for an easy-to-implement solution.

Comment: _"but I don't have control over it"_ - Are you saying you can't change the JavaScript in question? If not I don't understand how you think the problem could be fixed. You (they?) should be using [`.getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear).

Comment: Yes, they should be using .getfullyear(). And yes, I cannot alter the page from the server-side. 
Further, I am not sure the problem CAN be fixed. 
But I am asking the question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript function needs to be changed on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

This might allow you to put in a `if` that might just do the work.

**EDIT** I was wrong as comments pointed out that the method is no more active. I found out a post, a bit more complicated, which might just do the job. Look around.

[How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser)

Comment: Note the "*version deprecated: [1.3](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.3/), removed: [1.9](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.9/)*"