# How to get the HTTP protocol version via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http

Is it possible to determine the HTTP protocol version using JavaScript? I need to detect if the user is using HTTP/2 protocol (and congratulate him if this was the case).

Comment: Is your Javascript code running on the server end? If not (assuming client/browser end), what do you mean by "if the user is using http/2"?

Comment: I want to check this on client side. HTTP/2 is a new protocol and few browsers support it.

Comment: So what you really want to do is check what browser the user has (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser) and then check if its one of the versions listed here http://caniuse.com/#feat=spdy

Answer (score 6):

```js
console.log(performance.getEntries()[0].nextHopProtocol)
```

See also: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_performanceresourcetiming_nexthopprotocol

Works in

- Edge since 17
- Firefox (Desktop and Mobile) since 45
- Chrome (Desktop and Mobile) since 61
- Safari Mac 14.1 (tested here, but not yet updated on MDN/caniuse)

Answer (score -4):

```
if (location.protocol == "http/2"){
    alert('congratulations!');
}
```

Comment: For http and https protocols, this shows `http:` and `https:`, respectively - should it not be `http/2:`, then? Also, a link to some official documentation would be much valuable for future readers.

Comment: you are correct, Robert Rossman. I left out the colon in the protocol. I am not sure about the new protocol because I haven't seen it so I went with how the OP presented it.