# running specific code in js file pertaining to i.e9 v's all other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, modernizr

so it has come down to this one line of code... I am basically trying to create a part in my code that says do this if i.e9 but if not do this... here is the code...

```
('.fa-phone, .bg-darkPink').parent().on('click', function () {
      $('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(0, 0);



<<--IF I.E9 OR BELOW DO THIS THING--->>
    $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({
            Collapsed: true



              });
          <<--END OF I.E9 OR BELOW THING ----->>

  <<--I.E9 MUST ALSO IGNORE THIS LINE IN THE SCRIPT --->> 
  $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );

$MORE CODE 
$MORE CODE
```

it is part of a string of functions associated with a button.. for some reason i.e9 didn't like the function but the other way it did.. any help here would be awesome ...

p.s I am using modernizr 2.6.2 so have been reading up on its feature detection capabilities but can't get my head round it , please someone put me out of my misery ;p

beggining of solution EDIT

So far I have this ...

```
 $('.fa-phone, .bg-darkPink').parent().on('click', function () {
      $('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(0, 0);
      $('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(3000, 1); 
      $("#colorscreen").remove();
      $("body").append('<div id="colorscreen" class="animated"></div>');
      $("#colorscreen").addClass("fadeInUpBigCS");
      $(".tile-area-main").css({width: "720px",opacity:1}).load("contact-page.html #contact-form");
      $.getScript("js/slider/slider-animations.js");
      $(".submenu-ctn").load("contact-page.html .submenu-contact");
      $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');  

      if(browser.name=='msie'&&browser.version<=9) { 
       $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({Collapsed: true}); 
       }else { 
       $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' ); }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional comments in html:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  // Include script for ie9 and less here
<![endif]-->
```

Update:

You can use navigator object in Script to detect if it is ie9 or below.

```
navigator.appVersion
```

It return this:

```
clientVersion (platform; information; extraInformation)
```

example:

```
5.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98; Win 9x 4.90)
```

Check the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx)

Here is the code:

```
var flag = false;
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
// Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
  var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  return rv;
}
function checkVersion()
{
  var msg = "You're not using Internet Explorer.";
  var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion();

  if ( ver > -1 )
  {
    if ( ver == 9.0 ) 
      flag = true
    else
      flag = false
  }else{
  flag = false
}
}
```

Now check in you function if **flag is true** call the function else jump through

Update 3:

```
var ms_ie = false;
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var old_ie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
var new_ie = ua.indexOf('Trident/');

if ((old_ie > -1) || (new_ie > -1)) {
    ms_ie = true;
}

if ( ms_ie ) {
    //IE specific code goes here
}
```

Try this code

```
$('.fa-phone, .bg-darkPink').parent().on('click', function () {
      $('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(0, 0);
      $('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(3000, 1); 
      $("#colorscreen").remove();
      $("body").append('<div id="colorscreen" class="animated"></div>');
      $("#colorscreen").addClass("fadeInUpBigCS");
      $(".tile-area-main").css({width: "720px",opacity:1}).load("contact-page.html #contact-form");
      $.getScript("js/slider/slider-animations.js");
      $(".submenu-ctn").load("contact-page.html .submenu-contact");
      $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');  

// code started here

var ms_ie = false;
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var new_ie = ua.indexOf('Trident/5');   //only for ie9

    if ((new_ie > -1) {
        ms_ie = true;
    }

    if ( ms_ie ) {
        $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({Collapsed: true}); 
        }else{
    $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
    }
    });
```

Comment: ok so in the middle of my script i can just whack that in and say that , .... the next line of code breaks i.e 9 so i need to tell it to also ignore it how can i do this ?

Comment: You need to keep conditional comment in HTML. I will say use the updated method. Check if MSIE 6 to MSIE 9 are substring of navigator.appversion

Comment: Please check the latest update i have made. You can create a flag and check IE version.

Comment: that is very comprehensive AJ thanks ... i have pursued the other response to the question and am trying to get that to work .  i edited my question , any ideas ?

Comment: @havingagoatit : i have updated answer again, check update 3. It can't be any easier. I am not what the `browser` object is in depperm's answer.

Comment: ok i will try and integrate it into the functions i have posted at the bottom of my question

Comment: is it specific to i.e 9 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81479/discussion-between-havingagoatit-and-a-j).

Answer (score 1):

From [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser), second answer, use an if

```
if(browser.name=='msie'&&browser.version<=9)
   //do your stuff
```

Comment: That looks good to me , i am guessing the further use of "else" in the potential if statement would allow me to use both statements for all browsers ya think ?

Comment: i believe so, you may need to parseInt the version

Comment: can you explain ? my syntax and general understanding of jquery is weak

Comment: ok so far iv'e got this can you point me in the right direction ... if(browser.name=='msie'&&browser.version<=9) {
        $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({
        Collapsed: true
      } else {
        $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
    }

Comment: You have your braces in a twist, I believe this is correct:    if(browser.name=='msie'&&browser.version<=9) {
        $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({Collapsed: true});
}else {
        $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
    }

Comment: its getting stuck i have edited my initial question to put the block of code in at the bottom including the new statement can ya show me the way buddy

Comment: look at the code you posted at the bottom and fix the braces to match

Comment: yeah im having a go , as i do that i realise that the other bits are a continuation of the else part and i do still want the i.e9 part to do the rest , is there a way of avoiding duplication ?

Comment: hmmm it doesn't seem to be working even with the braces in the correct places

Comment: i just added the latest at the bottom with the braces fixed , doesn't seem to work though in firefox the menu is still closing even when i take the non i.e 9 code out ???