# check chrome version from console

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to detect Google Chrome's version from the console.
I know I can parse the user agent string - but I prefer a more concise way.

Here is what I currently have:

```
var uaStr = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var index = uaStr.indexOf('chrome/');
uaStr.substring(index +7,index+11);
```

I would like to know if there's a better way - something like `chrome.version()`

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like all solutions out there (at least the ones I could find via a quick search) use the User Agent, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser

Comment: [Chrome has some APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) a bit like the one you imagined, but as of this comment in 2019, there doesn't seem to be one for version. A future reader of this comment may find they've added it.

Answer (score 76):

In Chrome DevTools Console execute the following statement:

```js
 > navigator.appVersion.match(/.*Chrome\/([0-9\.]+)/)[1]
```

And you will get the version number as a string

```
 > "51.0.2704.103"
```

Comment: Thanks - but I don't see much difference between navigator.userAgent and navigator.appVersion.

Comment: If I run this on a Chromium browser, will it give me it's chromium version ?

Comment: @HarshPhoujdar, yes it works on chromium browser too.

Comment: The regex inside `match` uses a `capturing group` to match all numbers and the dots 1 or more times, `[1] gets the match of the resulting array at position 1 (zero based). Pos 0 is the app version, but without the final part Safari..