# How to determine which chromium version is used by QtWebEngine in Qt 5 at run-time?

Tags: qt, qt5, chromium, qtwebengine

I couldn't find any function in Qt 5 to determine which chromium version is used by `QtWebEngine`.

I don't want to hard-code the chromium version in my code because I frequently update my application and the chromium version is usually changed in each version. And also Qt is backward-compatible and it is possible to update it without updating my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct solution but looking at [the source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebengine.git/tree/src/core/content_browser_client_qt.cpp#n1036) You can see that it is used to set the default user agent:

```
std::string ContentBrowserClientQt::getUserAgent()
{
    // Mention the Chromium version we're based on to get passed stupid UA-string-based feature detection (several WebRTC demos need this)
    return content::BuildUserAgentFromProduct("QtWebEngine/" QTWEBENGINECORE_VERSION_STR " Chrome/" CHROMIUM_VERSION);
}
```

So it can be extracted from that data:

```
QString version;
QString user_agent = QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()->httpUserAgent();
for(const QString & text : user_agent.split(" ")){
    if(text.startsWith(QStringLiteral("Chrome/"))){
        version = text.mid(QStringLiteral("Chrome/").length());
    }
}
qDebug().noquote()<< "Qt version:" << QT_VERSION_STR << "chromium version:" << version;
```

Output:

```
Qt version: 5.14.2 chromium version: 77.0.3865.129
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`runJavaScript`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#runJavaScript) method to show a dialog box with the [`navigator.userAgent`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp) Javascript variable, which includes the Chromium version:

```
QWebEngineView webView;
webView.page()->runJavaScript("alert(navigator.userAgent)");
```

In my case, the alert box says the following:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.15.1 Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36

The interesting part for finding the Chromium version is `Chrome/80.0.3987.163`, which means that the Chromium version the Qt Web Engine is using is 80.0.3987.163.

Answer (score 1):

If you run QT with the [devtools](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-debugging.html#qt-webengine-developer-tools) allowed, you can get the chrome version inside the devtools that way :

```js
navigator.appVersion.match(/.*Chrome\/([0-9\.]+)/)[1]
```

This solution comes from this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735721/check-chrome-version-from-console).