# "await is not defined" error in Qt Web Engine

Tags: javascript, qt, async-await, chromium, qtwebengine

I'm trying to run Javascript code containing [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Op%C3%A9rateurs/await) in Qt's web engine. Here is a minimal example illustrating what I'm trying to do:

```cpp
QWebEngineView webView;
webView.page()->runJavaScript("await (new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100)))");
```

The problem is that when I run this, I get the following Javascript error (which Qt logs in Qt Creator's console):

> js: Uncaught ReferenceError: await is not defined

When I first saw this, I thought it was because Qt Web Engine uses an older version of Chromium that doesn't support `await`. But using the method from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64051120/4284627), I found out that that the version of Chromium it was using was Chromium 80, and according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_await), `await` is supported in Chromium 55 and later, so it should be supported in Chromium 80.

So my question is, why do I get this error even though it's using a version of Chromium that should support `await`, and how do I fix this?

Comment: await is only defined in a function that is `async` - though there is a flag for top-level await, but the answer below is good

Comment: @JaromandaX Do you know how to enable top-level await? I checked [`QWebEngineSettings`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html) but couldn't find anything in there.

Comment: probably not in the environment you are in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
webView.page()->runJavaScript("(async () => await (new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100))))()");
```

Comment: This works in the example I provided, but in my real code I need to return a value after the `await`, and embedding it in an `async` function returns a `Promise` object instead of the value I need.

Comment: You can use: `const x = () => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100))` And Then call function in async function as `(async () => { const z = await x(); })`

Comment: I ended up using `console.log` to pass the output to the C++ code, and I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47983559/4284627) to get that output.