# CSS specifically for Safari 6 and 7

Tags: javascript, css, safari

I have a client that needs me to support Safari 6 and up. I had to center some text on a rotating banner but the css to center on IE 9 and Safari 6 and 7 has to be different that what I would use on IE 10+ and Safari 8+. I already have an IE9 conditional statement in place for the IE9 fix but how do I get one in place for Safari 6 and 7? Do I need to browser sniff? Is there a conditional for Safari 6 and 7 only? Or is there a CSS hack for Safari 6 and 7. I have search all over but my searches aren't finding an answer for Safari 6 and 7.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be curious to know what centering technique is not applicable in Safari 6/7 versus Safari 8+. Also, just FYI, conditional comments are a non-standard IE exclusive feature.

Comment: I'm using the css centering from here for more modern browsers: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: .parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

Comment: but IE 9 and Safari 6 and 7 push that off to the right. So now I need:

Comment: position: absolute;
 width: 75%;
 top: 40%;
   left: 10%;
 text-align: center;

Comment: And have you tried adding `-webkit-transform: translate( ... );` (in addition to the transform prop)? IIRC, Safari has supported 2D transform since version 3 with the prefix.

Comment: I didn't use browser specific prefixes for that http://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-transform - but ultimately it doesn't support Safari 6 or 7

Comment: Did you click the 'SHOW ALL' button on CanIUse.com? It shows `transform` support goes back to Safari 3.1 with the `-webkit` prefix. If you actually tried it and it doesn't work in your scenario, so be it, but it is actually a good practice to include the prefixed properties, since that is why they are there. Using hacks or user-agent sniffing are not best practices.

Comment: Even IE9 claims to have support for transform with the `-ms` prefix according to caniuse.

Answer (score 0):

http://browserhacks.com/ is quite helpful. It offers some JS, Media Query, and CSS only browser filters.

I've used `var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement);` in my JS before with great success, but be careful, a lot of Safari bits also target Chrome (but it shows which browsers are affected on the site).

Comment: I've checked out browserhacks.com but i can't find anything for safari 6 and 7 specifically. i see something there for 6 but i need to cover both. if i can find a browser sniffer script for safari 6 and 7 i can have it insert embedded <style> with the changes i want but I've never done a browser sniffer before.

Answer (score 0):

A trust way, in my opinion is:

```
if (
navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 
&& 
navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1
)
```

Comment: how do i write it specifically for safari 6 and 7 so it doesn't run in later than safari 7?

Answer (score 0):

The final solution is here: [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser)

// I added this to the above solution to change the css
$(document).ready(function(){var browser = get_browser_info();if(browser.name == "Safari" && (browser.version == "5" || browser.version == "6" || browser.version == "7")){$(".centerCaption").css({"width": "75%", "top": "40%", "left": "12%"});}});