# Javascript to find processId of an item in taskmanager

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to find process id of a particular item in task manager by using its window name. Eg. To find process id of window "Google - Internet Explorer" from list of tasks using Javascript.

Comment: I don't think so. No. If you need to find out which browser is being used on your site, try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5918791/1524085

Answer (score 0):

No. Javascript only operates within the browser - whichever operating system the site uses is unknown to Javascript - all it can know about is the parent page(s) which launched it and which browser is being used.

Comment: Not from within the browser (to my knowledge). There is a way of communicating from Visual Studio to browser if the browser is launched from a VS program, but I've not tried it (and may only apply to IE).

Comment: okay. I read it can be done by WSH. But I did not get a working example. Can some one help ?

Comment: Not me, I'm afraid - WSH isn't my thing... Visual Basic, Javascript, PHP, ASP only.