# Show a message if the users's browser is older than: IE 10, Firefox 39, Chrome 39, Opera 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just like in the topic: how can I display a message (div) when an user uses browsers older than: IE 10, Firefox 39, Chrome 39, Opera 8? Or other words: how can I hide a div when an user uses browsers: IE 10+, Firefox 39+, Oper 8+ ?
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

Comment: jQuery.browser has been deprecated since 1.9.1 - NOT recommended to use this.

Answer (score 0):

you can Simply Check the browser details and version after that you can use your condition and implement the method of showing or hiding the `div` if the condition matched or not ?

```
function detectBrowser(){ 
    var N= navigator.appName; 
    var UA= navigator.userAgent; 
    var temp; 
    var browserVersion= UA.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i); 
    if(browserVersion && (temp= UA.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) 
    browserVersion[2]= temp[1]; 
    browserVersion= browserVersion? [browserVersion[1], browserVersion[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?']; return browserVersion; 
};
detectBrowser();
```