# semantic-ui javascript: how to check supported browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I want to check if user's browser support `semantic-ui` functionality and show error message in top of page, but allow to user proceed work with web site.

So is any function inside `semantic-ui` that check if current browser able to work with semantic, or to check if user's browser is bad, something like `isSemanticUiSupportThisBrowser()` 
?

I tried to grep source from here https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI via `find . -name "*.js" -exec grep -i browser {} \; -print` but can not find any function similar to what I want.

Comment: this might answer your question https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/4#issuecomment-30446129

Comment: That's old. Super old. They don't support IE9 anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantic UI does not provide this functionality as far as I'm aware.

They do provide a list of supported browsers. https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI

```
Browser Support
    Last 2 Versions FF, Chrome, Safari Mac
    IE 11+
    Android 4.4+, Chrome for Android 44+
    iOS Safari 7+
```

Check other topics such as [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser) for browser sniffing.

You can use a library such as modernizr (https://modernizr.com/) instead to feature sniff, but then you'll need to do the work to figure out what features you're sniffing for.