# How to detect if browser supports angular-material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I need to redirect users to our old website for browsers that can't handle Angular Material.

(1) I was thinking of detecting the browser agent and version, but I'm having trouble finding a definitive list for Chrome/Safari/Firefox of which browsers and versions actually work. Also the client detect code I tried didn't seem to return anything with iPhone 6/iOS9.

(2) Could I just detect a specific feature somehow, ie. flexbox, and use that to determine if the browser is unsupported?

Comment: I wouldn't bother checking version of Chrome / Safari / Firefox because they are autoupdated, and really old versions which won't support Angular Material are very very unlikely. There is only IE which you can check (but probably every IE >= 11 will work)

Comment: I've been doing some testing with BrowserStack Live. In our case IE10 works too. Safari iOS6 and lower doesn't work (iOS7, iOS8 and IOS9 work).

Comment: 4.2% of iOS users has now iOS6 and lower so hard to say. I wouldn't mind that and I would not support it, but I don't know your case.

Comment: Also, 6.2 Safari/desktop works. 6.0 doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the [docs](https://github.com/angular/material) shows that...

> .... Angular Material is targeted for all browsers with versions n-1; where n is the current browser version.

Assuming they keep this pace, you could query a website like [Browse Happy](http://browsehappy.com/) to find the latest version of the client browser, then compare it to [the version the client is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser).