# How to test the availability of asm.js in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, asm.js

Imagine I have a asmjs script but before running the script, I'd like to test and see if the browser supports asm.js or not. If it is `false`, display a message indicating that the browser is old or something like that, otherwise, execute the script.

Can we utilize the idea of `"use asm"` somehow to detect if a web browser supports asm.js?

```
function MyAsmModule() {
    "use asm";
    // module body
}
```

Comment: Might be non doable https://github.com/kangax/compat-table/issues/447

Comment: Why would you want to detect that? It may run a bit slower if its not supported.

Comment: @Jonasw do you think it is going to work even if the browser doesn't support ArrayBuffer for instance?

Comment: No, but i think you can test if ArrayBuffers are supported... if(!"ArrayBuffer" in this) throw Error("not supported");

Comment: By "support", do you mean being able to execute asm.js code or being able to optimize it?

Comment: @Maxime being able to optimize the code

Comment: what about `typeof(WebAssembly) == null`?

Comment: @TheChetan that would work but it doesn't check the asm.js availability.

Comment: Perhaps you can get the browser version and compare it with this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=asmjs

Comment: benchmark two other-wise identical functions and see if one is way faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sad situation is that there appear to be no real reliable way to detect browser support of asm.js.

Running this segment will produce an error, but not a catchable one:

```js
try {
  (function MyAsmModule() {"use asm"})();
  console.log("asm.js OK");
  // Now, hit F12 to open the browser console just to find a TypeError that states:
  // "asm.js type error: expecting return statement"
}
catch(err) {
  // will never show...
  console.log("asm.js not supported.");
}
```

This is one of those cases you unwillingly have to turn to client string checking, perhaps combined with other feature checking to [determine which browser and version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38080051/1693593) you're dealing with.

When that information is obtained then check this list which following browsers and versions supports ([courtesy of caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=asmjs)) asm.js, as of this date:

*Version number is since and including* - I included also browsers with very small user bases as the information was available for these as well:

```
Firefox             : v. 22
Chrome              : v. 28    (*)
Edge                : v. 13
Opera               : v. 15    (*)
Android browser     : v. 56    (*)
Opera mobile        : v. 37    (*)
Chrome for Android  : v. 59    (*)
Firefox for Android : v. 54
Samsung internet    : v.  5    (*)
QQ browser          : v.  1.2  (*)
Baidu browser       : v.  7.12 (*)
```

([*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm.js#Implementations)): "Chrome does not support Ahead-Of-Time compilation but performance doubled in Chrome 28"