# Hide Script tags From Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

Lets say if someone is accessing my website using a specific version of Chrome browser is there anyway to hide specific  tags so that they don't execute on that browser with that version?

I've tried to give the script tag an id and then display:none; and show it if it has that id but apparently you can't hide script tags with css? Looking for another solution.

I've seen this:

< ! [if lt IE 7] >

for internet explorer but I am unfamiliar with it and how to use it for chrome. I've just started to learn code again after 5 years and the stuff I try and accomplish seem to be difficult for an amateur coder lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you ask for, but in order to execute scripts in all webbrowsers but Google Chrome you can also do the following:

```
<script>
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

if(!is_chrome)
   {
      //Your Code goes here (won't be executed if it's Google Chrome)
   }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use conditional comments to hide things from Internet Explorer contrary to the answer from deceze. (These are different from comments used to show things to internet explorer which are more common, those are known as 'Downlevel hidden conditional comments')

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]><![if gte IE 7]><![endif]-->
<!-- This is a bit mad, but code inside here is served to everything 
    except browsers less than IE7, so all browsers will see this -->
<!--[if lte IE 6]><![endif]><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

"conditional comments" work only at older IE browser.
If you want to prevent to use some version or browser use:
https://github.com/mikemaccana/outdated-browser-rework or use function like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5918791/8770040. Then when user use a specific version of browser remove every thing form page or show some overlay element.