# Angular 8 chrome support

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I would like to know What is the minimum version of chrome that angular 8 supports and if there is a way of telling the user that he needs to update his chrome. 
my angular app doesn't work on some computers and i think this is the reason.

Comment: What kind of errors do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find Angular's official [supported browsers page](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support)

Angular 8 introduced differential loading which allows for loading of different javascript files es2015 vs es5 javascript for older browsers. meaning the correct versions get loaded depending on the browser. you have the option of adding additional polyfills to you build to target specific browsers.

as to informing the user that the browser they use is too old, this is a something that's been around for decades and you can find code to do that. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser) is an example

PS: It might help if you provided the specifics of the error your seeing in case it isnt' a browser issue.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But the article shows the maximum chrome version nit the minimum. And there are no errors in the console

Comment: I came here with the same question - Is there an official minimum version?  ie. I have a user on Chrome 67 - Should I expect to resolve all his browser problems?