# How to open a webpage only if the user is on Google chrome

Tags: javascript, php, browser, user-agent

i have a website that works perfectly but I would like to open a specific page on it only if the user is on a PC and more specifically with Chrome or Mozilla browser.

I found that this is possible with the user agent but I didn't know how to use it properly.

Comment: Why? Just load the page, _test whether the features you need are available_, and present the content if they are, or an alternative if they're not? Don't treat people differently based on their flavour of browser in 2020.

Comment: I agree, you are trying to solve a problem in the wrong direction. Let people fail on the site they are on, not on the site they are going to. You can warn them if you really want based on the [user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5918791/231316), but I would avoid that, too.