# AWS Cognito send invalid DeviceName in authEvents

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I used [CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminListUserAuthEvents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminListUserAuthEvents-property) for getting user auth events but received an invalid result. I logged in from Opera but Cognito displays that I used Chrome 8 (this is a mistake).

I could fix that if I get original `navigator.userAgent` (for example: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36 OPR/72.0.3815.400`), but I only received data like that:

```json
 {
    "EventId": ${EVENT_ID},
    "EventType": "SignIn",
    "CreationDate": ${CREATION_DATE},
    "EventResponse": "Pass",
    "EventRisk": {
      "RiskDecision": "AccountTakeover",
      "RiskLevel": "Low",
      "CompromisedCredentialsDetected": false
    },
    "ChallengeResponses": [
      {
        "ChallengeName": "Password",
        "ChallengeResponse": "Success"
      }
    ],
    "EventContextData": {
      "IpAddress": ${MY_IP_ADDR},
      "DeviceName": "Chrome 8, Linux",
      "City": ${MY_CITY},
      "Country": ${MY_COUNTRY}
    }
  }
```

I wouldn't like to make the crutch, to clarify this information, like creating `preauth` Cognito trigger which will log this information in another Table and handle this flow by myself

**UPD**:
crutch for detection browser I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser)

**UPD 2**:
The opened issue on the [official AWS Github repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3564)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug and AWS promises to fix it.
More information [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3564).