# Can I make a website only visible on chrome and redirect to other website when it's not chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, browser

I am trying to make a website with features only available on browsers with WebKit engines, So I wanted a website to be get loaded only when it detects WebKit browser and redirects to an alternative website if the host's browser doesn't use Webkit, Is it possible through Javascript or any Back-end languages? If yes, How can it be done?

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser

Comment: The best approach would be to use feature detection rather than browser sniffing. Can your browser do X, Y and Z? Then go ahead, I don't need to see your ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
    document.onload=function() { 
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") === -1 )
    {
      window.location.replace("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the traffic based on user agent to different endpoints before it arrives to your origin. It depends on your InfraStructure. for Ex you can use Big-IP or Stingray with TrafficScript or also with AWS-cloudfront and Lambda functions.