# Detect latest browser version in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, safari

**REQUIREMENT:** I want to compare user's browser version is latest one or not. So what I want is to check what browser i.e. IE, Chrome, FF or Safari and then what version of that browser is using. Then I need to check if the version user having is latest one or not. If it is not latest then I want to notify user with some custom user defined message.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE:** I'm able to detect user browser and version.

**PROBLEM**: How to check what is the latest version of that browser that user is using.

**NOTE**: I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720826/how-to-check-if-a-visitor-is-using-the-latest-version-of-his-her-browser) thread but I didn't find any answer.

Please let me know how to check the latest version of different browsers i.e. ***IE***, ***Chrome***, ***FF*** and ***Safari***.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you a webserver?

Comment: I guess you have to spoof the userAgent string. Just be aware that the user can change that string as he likes.
From MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent

Comment: Yes, I'm using a node.js for server end codes and it's running on HTTP.

Comment: Quentin: I didn't find my answer there. And that's the reason I have added the new question. Also in my question I have added that in NOTE section. Some answer links are showing 404 on the [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720826/how-to-check-if-a-visitor-is-using-the-latest-version-of-his-her-browser)

Comment: I agree with the duplicate target being a not useful, but duplicates are defined be the question, not the quality of the answers.

Comment: [Detect version of browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser)

Comment: @DeepakBiswal — If you want to encourage better answers for an existing question, put a bounty on it instead of duplicating it.

Answer (score -1):

**Edited answer as incorrectly answered due to not reading the question well enough.**

You can get the latest browser version in JSON, XML using a service such as http://fresh-browsers.com.

Then using `navigator.userAgent` you should be able to check the browser version.

Comment: That's quite out of date. And link-only answers are off-topic for stackoverflow anyway.

Comment: true, moved code into answer

Comment: That doesn't do version detection for any browser other than IE, so how can it tell if the latest version is installed? And it doesn't support IE 11.

Comment: The IE 11 user agent string is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko ` so `var ie11 = /MSIE 11.0/.test( navigator.userAgent );` will not match it.

Comment: Edited my answer, it was poor - ideally should be a comment to the above answer, can a answer be changed to a comment with a click of a button?